# select option displayed without dropdown

Tags: php

The Below code we are using. Please check and update:

`
 
               
                   dashboard

```
           </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="to_user">Turbine</label>
            <select name="to_user" class="form-control">
                <option value="pick">--Select All--</option>
                 <option>   <?php
                    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Turbine FROM [JMDWF].[dbo].[TENAVG]";

                    $sql = sqlsrv_query($link,$query);
                    $row = sqlsrv_num_rows($sql);
                    $menu = "";


                        echo "<select name='to_user'>";
                        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)){
                           /* echo "<option value='". $row['Turbine'] ."'>" .$row['Turbine'] ."</option>" ;*/
                           $menu.="<option>".$row['Turbine']."</option>";
                        }
                     echo "$menu";
                    ?>
                    </option>

            </select>


        </div>`
```

Still we getting output out of the drop down list. I need to show the values in drop down.

Comment: what is the meaning of writting **<select>** inside **<option></option>**

Comment: You should never print out another selection inside another select's option

Answer (score 0):

Your are printing the output from PHP into your `<option></option>` node of the html - it won't be visible.

Try this instead:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="to_user">Turbine</label>
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Turbine FROM [JMDWF].[dbo].[TENAVG]";
                $sql = sqlsrv_query($link,$query);
                $row = sqlsrv_num_rows($sql);
                $menu = "";
                echo "<select name='to_user'>";
                echo "<option value='pick'>--Select All--</option>";
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)){
                       /* echo "<option value='". $row['Turbine'] ."'>" .$row['Turbine'] ."</option>" ;*/
                       $menu.="<option>".$row['Turbine']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "$menu";
            ?>
    </div>`
```

Comment: there is a silly mistake you should advise developer and let them try to resolve by themselves.